# Run an executable as different user in linux without knowing the password

Tags: linux, permissions

There's an executable that's usually run by user A and writers in a directory only readable, writable, etc. by user A.  Is it possible to allow user B in the same group to run the executable as user A so that it writes in the same directories, etc., without user B knowing the password of user A and without having access to root (i.e. cannot use visudo)?

Comment: Would making the directory group-writable meet your requirements?

Comment: @KeithThompson I would prefer to have the resulting files owned by user A, though I may have to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using `chmod u+s` to setuid the executable to run with the effective ID of the owner of the executable.  More [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Comment: Note that this allows anyone with execute permission for the executable to run it as `A`. As with any security setting, paranoia is healthy.

Comment: Odd.  Wonder why someone downvoted my answer.

Comment: I have observed that this does not always work as intended in shell scripts or perl scripts.  Thus, a restricted sudo would be the approach without a lot of problems.

Comment: @mdpc Can you be more specific or perhaps give an example of what you mean by not working as intended?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: It's explained in the Unix FAQ [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html).

Answer (score 1):

Setting up `sudo` to allow B to execute a particular command as A would probably be the best and safest approach, but you said you can't use `visudo`.

Assuming your system has a working ssh server, you could add B's public key to `/home/A/.ssh/authorized_keys`. B could then run:

```
ssh A@localhost some_command
```

without having to know A's password.

The trouble is that this gives B full access to A's account. It's not quite as bad as giving B A's password.

There may be ways to set up ssh to permit B to run only certain commands, but I don't know what they are.

(`chmod u+s`, as [Nicole's answer](https://superuser.com/a/533741/92954) suggests, is probably cleaner; I should have thought of it.)

Comment: chmod is quicker/easier. I don't know about cleaner.